# html entities not displaying when passed by jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is my HTML code

```
 <input id="email" name="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
 <span id="emailInfo"></span>
```

This jQuery script which validates the input and prints a message within the span tags

```
 emailInfo.text("This email is already registered!");
```

This works prefect but when I try to print an HTML entity, it won't be recognized.

```
 emailInfo.text("&#x2713;");
```

`&#x2713;` = ✓

However, It would be recognized if I manually typed it anywhere in the HTML page.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch from [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), as jQuery's `text()` method does not parse the string as HTML, but inserts it as text, hence the entities won't be converted.

```
emailInfo.html("&#x2713;");
```